Create a curved bottom navigation bar with a square shaped curve
I am working on a project that requires a custom navigation bar in such a way that the curve is of a square shape and the floation button is also a square shape. the main issue is that I have kind of achieve this but then i have hardcoded the backgroundcolor of the square shaped middle curve.
I have different screens where I have scrollviews and when i scroll, i want the middle curve to take that color (i.e. be transparent with respect to screens that the bottom navigation bar is on).
dont suggest me libraries that help create curved bottom navigation bars, none of them support the use case I am looking for.
achieve so far

import React from 'react';
import { Svg, Path } from 'react-native-svg';
import { StyleProp, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';

interface TabCenterSvgProps extends React.PropsWithChildren<{}> {
  style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  fill?: string;  // Optional fill color for the Path
}

const TabCenterSvg: React.FC<TabCenterSvgProps> = ({ style, fill = "#f2f2f2", ...props }) => (
  <Svg
    width={90}
    height={35}
    fill="#f2f2f2"
    style={style}
    {...props}
  >
    <Path
      fill={fill}
      d="M10 0h70v25c0 5.523-4.477 10-10 10H20c-5.523 0-10-4.477-10-10V0zM10 10V0H0c5.523 0 10 4.477 10 10zm70 0V0h10c-5.523 0-10 4.477-10 10z"
    />
  </Svg>
);

export default TabCenterSvg;

import React, {useCallback, useMemo} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
import {BottomTabBarProps} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import TabCenterSvg from '../components/TabCenterSVG';
import HomeIcon from '../assets/images/svg/homeIcon.svg';
import HomeHighlighted from '../assets/images/svg/homeIconHighlighted.svg';
import ProfileIcon from '../assets/images/svg/profileIcon.svg';
import ProfileHighlighted from '../assets/images/svg/profileIconHighlighted.svg';
import AddIcon from '../assets/images/svg/BottomTabPlus.svg';
import {colors} from '../assets/colors/colors';
import Gradient from './Gradient';
import {BottomSheetStack} from '../navigation/BottomSheetNavigation';
import {
  useBottomSheet,
} from '../utils/BottomSheetContext.utils';
import {BottomSheetBackdrop, BottomSheetModal} from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';

export const CustomTabBar: React.FC<BottomTabBarProps> = ({
  state,
  navigation,
}) => {
  const getIconAndLabel = (routeName: string) => {
    const isFocused = state.routes[state.index].name === routeName;

    switch (routeName) {
      case 'Home':
        return {
          icon: isFocused ? <HomeHighlighted /> : <HomeIcon />,
          labelStyle: isFocused ? styles.labelFocused : styles.label,
        };
      case 'Profile':
        return {
          icon: isFocused ? <ProfileHighlighted /> : <ProfileIcon />,
          labelStyle: isFocused ? styles.labelFocused : styles.label,
        };
      default:
        return {
          icon: <AddIcon height={20} width={20} />,
          labelStyle: styles.label,
        };
    }
  };

  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['90%'], []);
  const {bottomSheetModalRef, openBottomSheet} = useBottomSheet();

  const renderBackdrop = useCallback(
    (props: any) => (
      <BottomSheetBackdrop
        {...props}
        appearsOnIndex={0}
        disappearsOnIndex={-1}
      />
    ),
    [],
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.tabBar}>
      <View style={styles.leftContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
          style={styles.tabButton}>
          {getIconAndLabel('Home').icon}
          <Text style={getIconAndLabel('Home').labelStyle}>Home</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.centerContainer}>
        <TabCenterSvg />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={openBottomSheet} style={styles.addButton}>
          <Gradient
            fromColor={colors.itemGradientStartColor}
            toColor={colors.itemGradientEndColor}
            height={60}
            width={60}
            borderBottomLeftRadius={10}
            borderBottomRightRadius={10}
            borderTopLeftRadius={10}
            borderTopRightRadius={10}>
            <AddIcon height={20} width={20} />

            <BottomSheetModal
              handleIndicatorStyle={{opacity: 0}}
              enablePanDownToClose={false}
              backgroundStyle={{borderRadius: 30}}
              handleStyle={{opacity: 0}}
              backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}
              ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
              snapPoints={snapPoints}>
              <BottomSheetStack />
            </BottomSheetModal>
            
          </Gradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
          style={styles.tabButton}>
          {getIconAndLabel('Profile').icon}
          <Text style={getIconAndLabel('Profile').labelStyle}>Profile</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabBar: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    bottom: 0,
    elevation: 2,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 70,
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  leftContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  centerContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'relative',
  },
  rightContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  tabButton: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  addButton: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -30,
    zIndex: 2,
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'grey',
    marginTop: 4,
  },
  labelFocused: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: '#1a46a4',
    marginTop: 4,
  },
  rounded: {
    borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
    borderTopRightRadius: 30,
  },
});

export default CustomTabBar;

I am expecting something like this.

